# JWS installation on the client system

Tags: java, java-web-start, java-6

need to install jws package on cleint in case it does not have it already installed. [this link](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/installguide-137230.html)says that there is a package javaws-1_2-windows-i586-i.exe package that can be used to install jws on the cleint but i see that this tutorial is pretty old, so had a doubt if it is still availble or some other way to install it on the client. ( dont want bulky JDK or something).
Does the cleint require to reboot the machine after the installation of JWS package?
If we get a JWS package can we host it locally for client?

Comment: *"( dont want bulky JDK or something)"* To install JWS on the client machine, they need to install the JRE (the JDK is for programmers).

Comment: is JRE independent of browser? i mean if chrome does not support java , does it be still giving an option to user for launching JNLP with JRE?